# Equilibria in Nonlinear Systems

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

For $x' = \sin x$ and  $y' = \cos y$,

(a) Find all of the equilibrium points and describe the behavior of the associated linearized system.

The equilibrium points I found are $(m\pi, \frac{\pi}{2}+n\pi)$ for $m,n$ are integers.
For each equilibrium $(x_m, y_n)$, the linearization is

$$
\begin{gather}
\begin{bmatrix}\cos x_m & 0\\ 0 & - \sin x_n \end{bmatrix}
\implies 
\begin{bmatrix} (-1)^m & 0\\ 0 & (-1)^n \end{bmatrix}.
\end{gather}
$$

For $m$ odd and $n$ odd, the system is sink;

For $m$ even and $n$ even, the system is source;

For one even and one odd, the system is saddle.

Is this right? Do I answer part (a) completely?

(b) Describe the phase portrait for the nonlinear system.

How to draw and describe the phase portrait for this system?

(c) Does the linearized system accurately describe the local behavior near the equilibrium points?

What am I comparing? Could anyone show me?

Comment: Which part of my text do you refer to?

Comment: yes they are...but you comment answers which part of my questions?

Comment: do you have any software I can use online to draw those graphs?\

Comment: i am going to solve this later with other software...please leave your comments here

Comment: Yes...i solved this...thx